# The article was cut when using LaTeX. About layout

Tags: latex

I'm writing a treatise, but the text is cut.
Of course, the goal is to normalize the layout. It was expected that I could write natural sentences as before, but in reality, the sentences were cut.

I wrote it normally, but it didn't meet my needs because the sentences were cut off.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run to see what's happening.

Comment: DON'T IGNORE ERRORS. There is no point in even looking at the output as long as your document does not compile. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document. The output does not necessarily make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to resolve my error. It seems that the usage of ”width” is wrong. I'm a beginner, so I'm trying to understand why I didn't provide a minimal practical example.

Comment: @CécileHonda `width` as such is not wrong, but you should give it some sensible length, e.g. `\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{images/SRL}` (also the notice the absence of file extension)

Comment: @CécileHonda Maybe useful for you: https://www.learnlatex.org/

Comment: @http://samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz/ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really must not ignore error messages! There is no point in even looking at the output as long as your document does not compile. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document. The output does not necessarily make sense.

That being said, `\end{figure}` is missing. Overleaf even marks this with a big red `X` and the `.log` file would tell you what is wrong. Without the `\end{figure}` the rest of the document is set as part of the figure environment and thus not able to break package.

Furthermore, your figure is missing floating specifier, I suggest to use `\begin{figure}[htbp]`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've tried [hbtp] and it's very useful. Thank you very much!